# How to save edit profile in django

Tags: python, django

How can i save edited information in my Django.
I want to edit user profile and want to save them into my database.
for this i had made this method

```
@login_required()
def saveProfile(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        print "heloo"
        usr=request.POST['username']
        first_name=request.POST['first_name']
        last_name=request.POST['last_name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        mobile=request.POST.get('mobile_no')
        exp=request.POST.get('experience')
        skills=request.POST.get('Skills')
        edu=request.POST.get('education')
        linkedin=request.POST.get('linkedin_id')
        print first_name
        updated_values={'first_name': first_name}
        Consultants.objects.filter(user__username=usr).update(skills=skills, user__first_name=first_name )

    return HttpResponse("your account is updated succesfully")
```

Now when i execute the above code ,it saves the skills information but throws a error message `Consultants has no field named 'user__first_name`'
How can i access OneToOne model field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update two db tables in one update-statement. You have to update the `Consultants` (name it `Consultant` pls) and `User` models separately:

```
cons = Consultants.objects.filter(user__username=usr)
# update profile model
cons.update(skills=skills)  
# update user model
User.objects
    .filter(id__in=cons.values_list('user_id', flat=True))
    .update(first_name=first_name)
```

Beyond that, I recommend you to use a [django model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) for `Consultant`, add the fields for the `User` and override the `save` method in order to save the related `User` instance.